# IOS13 LaunchScreen image issue

Tags: image, launch, ios13, xcode11

I use LaunchScreen.storyboard. 
I have a single label and an image.

On Xcode11.0 (just installed), when build is done, I have this warning :
"'UILaunchImages' has been deprecated, use launch storyboards instead."
I already use LaunchScreen.storyboard !

When the app run on IOS13.1, the label is correctly shown, background color is ok, but the image don't appear !

[image]

[image]

is anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Do you have a LaunchIamge asset in your Assets.xcassets? This could be causing the warning. Not sure about the image not appearing, though.

Comment: thanks. You're right. I forgot to add an image !